# How to split camera display into pieces and show them in real time - Android

Tags: android, camera, split, real-time, preview

I have question about real-time camera display in android. Is there any way to split real-time camera display into pieces and show them randomly in the view, and if there is how to achieve it?

Comment: try using PreviewCallback interface

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of [setPreviewDisplay()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.html#setPreviewDisplay%28android.view.SurfaceHolder%29) you can call [setPreviewTexture()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.html#setPreviewTexture%28android.graphics.SurfaceTexture%29), and use the full power of OpenGL to display this texture in multiple facets.